# MATLAB: code for restarted gmres

Tags: matlab, linear-solver, iterative-method, gmres

I have a question about Matlab and restarted gmres. I would like to use `gmres.m` [provided here](http://www.netlib.org/templates/matlab/gmres.m). This code seems to be popular for the scientific computation newcomer. I also want to modify this code for my particular case.

But I have a question about recording the number of matrix-vector products and the
2-norm of each residual vector. If you use the built-in function `gmres.m` (e.g., `gmres(30)`) to solve a linear system, one obtains

```
iter = [17,20], % the total number of matrix-vector products is (17 - 1)*30 + 12 (= 492).
```

and `resvec`, a $493\times1$ vector.

Moreover, in the `gmres.m` function these two outputs are not available. As you know, we always call the gmres.m in MATLAB in the following style:

```
[x, flag, relres, iter, resvec] = gmres(A, b, restart, tol, maxit);
```

Then, I want to use these outputs to plot the convergence histories, i.e.,

X-axis: the number of matrix-vector products,

Y-axis: 2-norm of relative residual, i.e., `norm(b - Ax_m)/norm(b);`

So, how can I record this two outputs reasonably in the modified `gmres.m`? Despite my many attempts to deal with this problem, I still fail to manage it. It makes me very confused, especially for recording `resvec`. Can anyone provide suggestions for handling this problem?

Comment: What is `resvec`? Are you possibly reading documentation for another implementation of gmres (such as Matlab's [`gmres`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gmres.html)) instead of that in the code you linked to? Have you set your `path` or working directory (`pwd`) correctly so that you're calling your `gmres` instead of Matlab's function of the same name?

Comment: @horchler Thank you for your answer, "resvec" is a vector of the residual norms at each inner iteration, i.e, norm(b - A*x_m), including norm(b -A*x0). I see your meaning, but I want to write my own gmres codes, because I need to extend it to solve some new kind of linear systems.  

I want to plot a figure of convergence histories,  x-axis:  the number of matrix-vector products, 
y-axis: the "resvec"

Answer (score 5):

Technically, the template Matlab code provided at [Netlib](http://www.netlib.org/templates/matlab/gmres.m) already calculates the obtained residual at every iteration. It's just not recorded in the way that this is an output of the subroutine.

After each iteration `iter` the residual `r` is calculated, so one just needs to record it. I will do it right after it is calculated in the residual vector `resvec(iter)`.

Now, the provided GMRES code is not optimal (for example, the residual `r` is calculated both before and after the loop over `i`-variable: construction of the orthonormal basis), so I am not going to optimize that behaviour, but just count matrix-vector products (MVP) every time they happen in `mvp_count`. Then, at the end of each iteration, I will record the number of actually performed MVPs in `mvpvec(iter)`.

Both `resvec` and `mvpvec` are added to the output parameters of the `gmres` function which should provide enough information to do the plot.

Notes:

- `mvpvec(iter)` counts MVPs performed **BY** the end of the `iter`th iteration by this particular implementation of `gmres`.
- no normalization by the 2-norm of the RHS `b` is done (to avoid confusion between residul, relative error, etc.). Should be easily changed either inside or outside of the function.
- only MVPs with the supposedly large original matrix $A$ are being counted
- the initial residual and the corresponding MVP (before iterative process starts) are not recorded.

Here is the slightly modified Matlab code.

```
function [x, error, iter, flag, resvec, mvpvec] = gmres( A, x, b, M, restrt, max_it, tol )

%  -- Iterative template routine --
%     Univ. of Tennessee and Oak Ridge National Laboratory
%     October 1, 1993
%     Details of this algorithm are described in "Templates for the
%     Solution of Linear Systems: Building Blocks for Iterative
%     Methods", Barrett, Berry, Chan, Demmel, Donato, Dongarra,
%     Eijkhout, Pozo, Romine, and van der Vorst, SIAM Publications,
%     1993. (ftp netlib2.cs.utk.edu; cd linalg; get templates.ps).
%
%     Sligtly modified by Anton Menshov to answer CompSci SE question in 2018.
%
% [x, error, iter, flag, resvec, mvpvec] = gmres( A, x, b, M, restrt, max_it, tol )
%
% gmres.m solves the linear system Ax=b
% using the Generalized Minimal residual ( GMRESm ) method with restarts .
%
% input   A        REAL nonsymmetric positive definite matrix
%         x        REAL initial guess vector
%         b        REAL right hand side vector
%         M        REAL preconditioner matrix
%         restrt   INTEGER number of iterations between restarts
%         max_it   INTEGER maximum number of iterations
%         tol      REAL error tolerance
%
% output  x        REAL solution vector
%         error    REAL error norm
%         iter     INTEGER number of iterations performed
%         flag     INTEGER: 0 = solution found to tolerance
%                           1 = no convergence given max_it
%         resvec   REAL (iter x 1) vector of norm2 solution resuduals at each iteration
%         mvpvec   INTEGER (iter x 1) vector of ACTUALLY computed MVPs at each iteration

iter = 0;                                         % initialization
flag = 0;
mvp_count =0;

bnrm2 = norm( b );
if  ( bnrm2 == 0.0 ), bnrm2 = 1.0; end

r = M \ ( b-A*x );     % not recorded and MVP is not counted
error = norm( r ) / bnrm2;
if ( error < tol ) return, end

[n,n] = size(A);                                  % initialize workspace
m = restrt;
V(1:n,1:m+1) = zeros(n,m+1);
H(1:m+1,1:m) = zeros(m+1,m);
cs(1:m) = zeros(m,1);
sn(1:m) = zeros(m,1);
e1    = zeros(n,1);
e1(1) = 1.0;


for iter = 1:max_it,                                    % begin iteration
     r = M \ ( b-A*x );   mvp_count = mvp_count+1;
     V(:,1) = r / norm( r );
     s = norm( r )*e1;
     for i = 1:m,                                       % construct orthonormal
         w = M \ (A*V(:,i));   mvp_count = mvp_count+1; % basis using Gram-Schmidt
         for k = 1:i,
             H(k,i)= w'*V(:,k);
             w = w - H(k,i)*V(:,k);
         end
         H(i+1,i) = norm( w );
         V(:,i+1) = w / H(i+1,i);
         for k = 1:i-1,                              % apply Givens rotation
             temp     =  cs(k)*H(k,i) + sn(k)*H(k+1,i);
             H(k+1,i) = -sn(k)*H(k,i) + cs(k)*H(k+1,i);
             H(k,i)   = temp;
         end
         [cs(i),sn(i)] = rotmat( H(i,i), H(i+1,i) ); % form i-th rotation matrix
         temp   = cs(i)*s(i);                        % approximate residual norm
         s(i+1) = -sn(i)*s(i);
         s(i)   = temp;
         H(i,i) = cs(i)*H(i,i) + sn(i)*H(i+1,i);
         H(i+1,i) = 0.0;
         error  = abs(s(i+1)) / bnrm2;
         if ( error <= tol ),                        % update approximation
            y = H(1:i,1:i) \ s(1:i);                 % and exit
            x = x + V(:,1:i)*y;
            break;
         end
     end

     if ( error <= tol ), break, end
     y = H(1:m,1:m) \ s(1:m);
     x = x + V(:,1:m)*y;                            % update approximation
     r = M \ ( b-A*x ); mvp_count = mvp_count+1;    % compute residual
     resvec(iter) = r;                              % store the residual AT the iter's iteration
     mvpvec(iter) = mvp_count;                      % store ACTUALLY performed MVP count BY iter's iteration
     s(i+1) = norm(r);
     error = s(i+1) / bnrm2;                        % check convergence
     if ( error <= tol ), break, end;
end

if ( error > tol ) flag = 1; end;                 % converged
% END of gmres.m
```